# Display contents in pdf similar to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a HTML to PDF converter which will display the contents of a webpage in a PDF format . So far I am able to get the information but the data is shown in a different order .

When I display **vDIV.innerHTML**  on webpage it displays correctly . But similar thing I tried doing on the PDF but i am unable to do it . Following is my working code where the PDF is downloaded .

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>fromHTML EX</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://parall.ax/parallax/js/jspdf.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function PDF1()
{
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var elementHandler = {

    };

    vDiv = document.getElementById("divExport");
    var vTable = '<br>';
    vTable += '<table class="wrs_export">';
    vTable += '<tr class="wrs_export">';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export">Radio ID</th>';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export">Description</th>';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export" colspan="2">Additional Info</th>';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export">Location</th>';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export">Start Time</th>';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export">Duration</th>';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export">Result</th>';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export">Failure Type</th>';
    vTable += '<th class = "wrs_export">Corrective Action</th>';
    vTable += '</tr>';

    vDiv.innerHTML = vTable;

    doc.fromHTML(
      vTable,
      150,
      15,
      {
        'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
      });
      doc.open("datauri");
}
```

as per the webpage the information is displayed in a sequential manner but i am getting in a vertical manner. I tried to put the vDiv.innerHTML  inside the doc.fromHTML but still I am not able to display the exact same thing in the webpage . AM i missing something ? Please help